# CRM Fetch XML in SSRS

Tags: xml, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, fetch

I simply added a field from the same entity into my fetch XML code by copying one line and replacing the name with the field name in CRM. The value I need comes through however when I preview the report `<TR><CR>` are showing up on my report.EX: John Doe `<TR><CR>` How can I add a field to my report fetch XML without `<TR><CR>` showing up when I preview it? I simply added:
"new_ofmonthstostrip" to the code below

```
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="new_loan">
    <attribute name="new_loanid" />
    <attribute name="new_balance" />
    <attribute name="new_principalbalance" />



    <attribute name="new_titlereserve" />
    <attribute name="new_contractreserve" />
    <attribute name="new_dealerguarantee" />

    <attribute name="new_uaiaccountnumber" />
    <attribute name="new_borrowerfirstname" />
    <attribute name="new_borrowerlastname" />
    <attribute name="new_dealerguarantee" />
    <attribute name="new_dealerstocknumber" />

    <attribute name="dc_musemodifiedbalance" />
    <attribute name="dc_musemodifiedfrequency" />
    <attribute name="dc_musemodifiedpayment" />

    <attribute name="dc_mmodifiedbalance" />
    <attribute name="dc_mmodifiedpaymentfrequency" />
    <attribute name="dc_mmodifiedpaymentamount" />


    <filter type="and">
      <filter type="or">
        <condition attribute="new_loanstatus" operator="eq" value="2" />
        <condition attribute="new_loanstatus" operator="eq" value="3" />
      </filter>
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="quote" from="quoteid" to="new_proposalid" alias="aa">
      <attribute name="quotenumber" />
     <attribute name = "new_ofmonthstostrip"/>
      <attribute name="new_reservearpercent" />
      <attribute name="new_reservear" />
      <attribute name="new_biddingon" />
      <attribute name="new_closingbid" />
      <attribute name="new_bonuspoolpercent" />
      <attribute name="new_reservearpercent" />
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="quoteid" operator="eq" value="@QuoteId" />
    </filter>
      <link-entity name="opportunity" from="opportunityid" to="opportunityid" alias="ab">
        <attribute name="new_biddingon" />

      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have accidentally removed the attribute name tag for this field when adding in the new_ofmonthstostrip attribute.  You also

```
<link-entity name="quote" from="quoteid" to="new_proposalid" alias="aa">
      <attribute name="quotenumber" />
      new_ofmonthstostrip
      <attribute name="new_reservearpercent" />
```

Change it to this:

```
<link-entity name="quote" from="quoteid" to="new_proposalid" alias="aa">
      <attribute name="quotenumber" />
      <attribute name = "new_ofmonthstostrip" />
      <attribute name="new_reservearpercent" />
```

Comment: That was a typo, the field is in the attribute name  like you have it above. However,the <tr><cr> still shows up when I preview the report.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `.dat` file in your project code of the report. VS tends to use the old data when you change something to the report and run it again. It's comparable to some sort of "cache" memory.

Other thing is always try to run it in `crm` itself. The results are more reliable when run on `crm`.